# Direct access user memory from kernel on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, kernel

I've got a user-mode process and kernel module. Now I want to read certain regions of usermode process from kernel, but there's one catch: no copying of usermode memory and simple access by VA.
So what we have: task_struct for target process, other related structs (like mm_struct, vma_struct) and virtual address like 0x0070abcd that I want to read or rather map somehow to my kernel module.

I can get page list using get_user_pages for desired memory regions, but what next? Should I map pages somehow into kernel and then try to read them as continuous memory region or there are better solutions?

Comment: Not an answer since I can't currently verify the details, but I suggest you take a look at `mm/memory.c`, at the implementation of `access_process_vm`.

Comment: Looks like access_process_vm calls copy_from_user_page. I don't want to copy userspace pages unless it's the only solution available.

Comment: `copy_from_user_page` seems to be a simple `memcpy()` most of the time, some arch/platform implementations appear to handle D/I cache first. I'd recommend caution unless you know that you're running on x86 or similar.

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question from `Robert Love`, the author of `Linux Kernel Development`: https://www.quora.com/Linux-Kernel-How-does-copy_to_user-work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "looking" at user-space requires locking a ton of stuff. So it's better that you do a short copy than leave everything locked for arbitrary amounts of time.  Your user-space process may not be VM-mapped into the current CPU. In fact, it may be entirely swapped out to disk, running on another CPU, in the middle of it's own kernel call, etc.

[Linux Kernel: copy_from_user - struct with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698396/linux-kernel-copy-from-user-struct-with-pointers)