# Passing linked list via copy_from_user

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linked-list, system-calls

I'm working on a linux project. I need to pass a linked list to the kernel from a userspace program. I have used the kernel way of implementing linked lists in userspace. I have defined a structure as follows:

`struct time{
    int val;
    struct list_head* list;
    };`

The variable for this strucure would be:

```
struct time mylist;
```

I have given the input data and used list_add function found in linux/include/list.h to link the structures.
This mylist is a part of another structure:

```
struct params{
int data1;
struct time* mylist;
};
```

Suppose I get all the data and store it in,

```
struct params param;
```

Now if I pass `&param` to a system call, and use `copy_from_user()` function there, will I be able to access the list ? I read that I cannot dereference a pointer in kernel space  (which points to a data in userspace) and that I'll have to use `copy_from_user` function again in [Linux Kernel: copy_from_user - struct with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698396/linux-kernel-copy-from-user-struct-with-pointers). Could anyone suggest me a possible way of passing this list to the kernel space ?

Comment: For each node, create a new node in kernel space, copy the user-space node in via `copy_from_user()`, and update the pointer to the newly created kernel space node.  Repeat.  This is messy.  Consider a different API for talking to the kernel.

Comment: @Peter I read that mmap() could be used to share memory between userspace and kernel space. But I'm not working on kernel modules. Will mmap() work in my case ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean that "you are not working on kernel modules".  Module vs. main kernel doesn't matter.  No, `mmap()` will not help with the linked list, because kernel-space and user-space still have different virtual addresses for the same memory, which means the "next" pointer of the list needs to be different for each.  Really, a linked list is not an appropriate structure for communicating with the kernel.